# How to merge CSV with JSON D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to merge two datasets based on their shared value 'starting point'. I'm loading data.csv and adding the values 'color' and 'path' from newdata.json to data (the CSV data)

I'm getting errors that newdata is not recognised.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null
```

What do I need to do to make it valid?

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {

d3.json("newdata.json", function(newdata) { 

    data.forEach(function(exp) {

      var result = newdata.filter(function(newd) {
        return exp['starting point'] === newd['starting point'];
      });

      exp.color = (result[0] !== undefined) ? result[0].color : null;
      exp.path = (result[0] !== undefined) ? result[0].path : null;

    })
})
});
```

Here is a [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/kbeZ4eTEtH6cFh9xX5vJ?p=info) with my data

Comment: There is one mistake `d3.json(url,[callback])` here in callback `function(error, json){}`. But in your code you've written `newd` which holds `null` means no error and you need to write one more parameter, that will hold your `json`. So finally you need to modify `d3.json('newdata.json', function(newdata){}` with `d3.json('newdata.json', function(error, newdata){}`. Try it
[Read this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I think I may need to do something else to get JSON in the right format? Here is a plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/kbeZ4eTEtH6cFh9xX5vJ?p=info

Comment: Hey, there is error in your json. remove that `;` in newdata.json file and see the result. Updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xCV7sROJHmoDCgx9OeP5?p=preview)

Comment: Ah so simple! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Plunker was showing error, how did you missed it.

Comment: I wrote the error I was getting in my question, and didn't know json couldn't contain ;

Comment: Well, Kindly pay attention while learning new things.... Analyze Observe Understand. Will be helpful. :D